# Swift - enum with button.tag?

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, ios8

i have this code in ObjC
and i want or trying to convert it to swift

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, BB3Photo) {
kirkenType = 10 ,
festenType = 20 ,
praestType = 30
};

@property (nonatomic, assign) BB3Photo selectedPhotoType;


- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {
if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    UIButton *button = sender;
    _selectedPhotoType = button.tag;
}
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Vælg Billed"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Vælg fra Biblioteket", @"Vælg Kamera", nil];
sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[sheet showInView:[self.view window]];
```

}

here's what i have made from it

```
    enum BBPhoto1: Int {
    case kommunen = 10
    case sagsbehandler = 20
    case festen = 30
}

var selectedPhoto = BBPhoto1.self

@IBAction func changeImage(sender: AnyObject){
    if sender .isKindOfClass(UIButton){
        let button: UIButton = sender as UIButton
        selectedPHoto = (sender as UIButton).tag as BBPhoto1 // doesent work "cannot assign that result as expression"
        selectedPHoto = button.tag // doesnt work either "cannot assign that result as expression"
        self.selectedPhoto = BBPhoto1.fromRaw((sender as UIButton).tag) // nope "cannot convert the expressions type () to type UIButton"

    }
}
```

i want to be able to have a switch statement with button tags to the same funktion but different in the code

Comment: why not `@IBAction func changeImage(sender: UIButton) {...` directly? are you expecting other types of _senders_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `tag` as the raw value of your `BBPhoto1` enum. You can do this with conditional unwrapping:

```
@IBAction func changeImage(sender: AnyObject){
    if let button = sender as UIButton {
        if let photoType = BBPhoto1.fromRaw(button.tag) {
            self.selectedPhoto = photoType
        }
    }
}
```

There's also a problem with the declaration of your `selectedPhoto` property. It should be:

```
var selectedPhoto: BBPhoto1?
```

The way you have it now it doesn't hold a `BBPhoto1` value, but instead the *type* of `BBPhoto1` itself.

---

Note that the `fromRaw` syntax has changed to an initializer in Xcode 6.1:

```
@IBAction func changeImage(sender: AnyObject){
    if let button = sender as UIButton {
        if let photoType = BBPhoto1(rawValue: button.tag) {
            self.selectedPhoto = photoType
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BBPhoto1 is not convertible to BBPhoto1.Type

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
@IBAction func changeImage(sender: AnyObject){
    if sender .isKindOfClass(UIButton){
        let button: UIButton = sender as UIButton
        selectedPHoto = BBPhoto1.fromRaw(button.tag)
    }
}
```

or (shorter):

```
@IBAction func changeImage(sender: UIButton){
    selectedPHoto = BBPhoto1.fromRaw(sender.tag)
}
```

Comment: doesnt work either of them, it saysCannot convert the expressions type () to type

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Not the same code; as in validating a text field, but the same principle in Swift 4, iOS 11, xCode 9.2.

```
enum SFT: Int {
    case StudentNameFieldTag
    case StudentIDFieldTag
    case StudentClassFieldTag
    case ChallengeCodeFieldTag
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == SFT.StudentClassFieldTag.rawValue {
        let whitespaceSet = CharacterSet.whitespaces
        if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: whitespaceSet) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fromRaw()` method returns an optional, so you have to declare your property as optional:

```
var selectedPHoto: BBPhoto1?
```

and use this code:

```
self.selectedPhoto = BBPhoto1.fromRaw((sender as UIButton).tag)
```

Alternatively, you can unwrap the `fromRaw` return value:

```
self.selectedPHoto = BBPhoto1.fromRaw((sender as UIButton).tag)!
```

Note however that in this case, if the raw value doesn't map to an enum, a runtime exception will be raised.